# Join multiple table with symbol added

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 queries to get row from multiple table. Those queries already tested and returning row I desire.

Here the 1st query.

```
select mst_province.provinsi as provinsi, mst_kab.kabupaten as kabupaten, form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite as nama 
from form_kuesioner_pengelola 
join form_kuesioner_surveyor on form_kuesioner_surveyor.namalokasi = form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite 
join mst_province on mst_province.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov 
join mst_kab on mst_kab.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov and mst_kab.id_kab = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab 
group by form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite 
order by form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov, form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab
```

I show them in table with symbol added

```
echo "<tr> <th>No.</th> <th>Provinsi</th> <th>Kabupaten</th> <th>Namasite</th> <th>Form Manfaat</th> <th>Form Pengelola</th> <th>Form Surveyor</th> <th>status</th>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rdata)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $no . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['provinsi'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['kabupaten'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>&#9989;</td>';
    echo '<td>&#9989;</td>';
    echo '<td>&#9989;</td>';
    echo '<td>complete</td>';

    echo "</tr>";
    $no++;
}
```

2nd one

```
select mst_province.provinsi as provinsi, mst_kab.kabupaten as kabupaten, form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite as nama 
from form_kuesioner_pengelola 
join mst_province on mst_province.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov 
join mst_kab on mst_kab.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov and mst_kab.id_kab = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab 
group by form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite 
order by form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov, form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab
```

And I show them in table as below

```
echo "<tr> <th>No.</th> <th>Provinsi</th> <th>Kabupaten</th> <th>Namasite</th> <th>Form Manfaat</th> <th>Form Pengelola</th> <th>Form Surveyor</th> <th>status</th>";

while($rowtable = mysqli_fetch_array($rdatatable)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $notable . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rowtable['provinsi'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rowtable['kabupaten'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $rowtable['nama'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>&#9989;</td>';
    echo '<td>&#10006;</td>';
    echo '<td>&#10006;</td>';

    echo '<td>visited</td>';

    echo "</tr>";
    $notable++;
}
```

The Problem is they printed with their own table and it returns me 2 table this way. How can I join them together so I have 1 table with different Symbol based on their own table.
Thanks

Comment: Using left join to combine them I guess might help(?)

Comment: Why does the first query join with `form_kuesioner_surveyor` but it doesn't use any columns from that table?

Comment: The second query looks like it returns everything that the first query returns, plus any rows that don't have a match in `form_kuesioner_surveyor`. So you're going to get lots of duplication when you combine them. Is that what you want?

Comment: Or do you just want all of them, and either `Complete` or `Visited` depending on whether they're in `form_kuesioner_surveyor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two queries using `UNION`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select 'complete' as which, mst_province.provinsi as provinsi, mst_kab.kabupaten as kabupaten, form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite as nama, form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov, form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab
    from form_kuesioner_pengelola 
    join form_kuesioner_surveyor on form_kuesioner_surveyor.namalokasi = form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite 
    join mst_province on mst_province.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov 
    join mst_kab on mst_kab.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov and mst_kab.id_kab = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab 
    group by form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite 

    UNION ALL

    select 'visited' as which, mst_province.provinsi as provinsi, mst_kab.kabupaten as kabupaten, form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite as nama, form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov, form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab
    from form_kuesioner_pengelola 
    join mst_province on mst_province.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov 
    join mst_kab on mst_kab.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov and mst_kab.id_kab = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab 
    group by form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite 
) AS u
order by u.idprov, u.idkab
```

Then you can use `$row['which']` to know whether to put `&#9989;` or `&#10006;` in the last two columns.

```
echo "<tr> <th>No.</th> <th>Provinsi</th> <th>Kabupaten</th> <th>Namasite</th> <th>Form Manfaat</th> <th>Form Pengelola</th> <th>Form Surveyor</th> <th>status</th>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rdata)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $no . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['provinsi'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['kabupaten'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>&#9989;</td>';
    echo '<td>' . ($row['which'] == 'complete' ? '&#9989;' : '&#10006;') . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . ($row['which'] == 'complete' ? '&#9989;' : '&#10006;') . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['which'] . '</td>';

    echo "</tr>";
    $no++;
}
```

If you just want to return everything once, with either `Complete` or `Visited` depending on whether they're in the `form_kuesioner_surveyor` table, you should use a `LEFT JOIN` with that table. Then you can test whether a column from the table is null or not, to know whether there was a match.

```
select IF(form_kuesioner_surveyor.namalokasi IS NULL), 'visited', 'complete') as which, mst_province.provinsi as provinsi, mst_kab.kabupaten as kabupaten, form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite as nama
from form_kuesioner_pengelola 
join mst_province on mst_province.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov 
join mst_kab on mst_kab.id_prov = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov and mst_kab.id_kab = form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab 
left join form_kuesioner_surveyor on form_kuesioner_surveyor.namalokasi = form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite     
group by form_kuesioner_pengelola.namasite 
order by form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov, form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab
```

Comment: it would be printed with &#9989; first, after that rows contain &#10006;.
can I join them with order by idprov and idkab

Comment: or is that possible to join them as a single query tho?

Comment: I've changed the answer to show how to combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: Hey Thanks @Barmar . But it returns error when all query inside alias u ordered by u.idprov - Unknown column 'u.idprov' in 'order clause'

Comment: You need to add those columns to the `SELECT` clause so they're returned from the union.

Comment: It also returning multiple row for 'namasite' when they are in present in "complete" and "visited". Can it be done to return only 1 'namasite' so if they already present in "complete" they wont appear in "visited"
Cheers!

Comment: Isn't that what I asked in my comment above?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to combine them into a single query.

Comment: My Bad ;). Complete or visited depending on whether they're in form_kuesioner_surveyor.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar . It such a great help. Cheers!